# VB failed to retrieve data from ETABS

Tags: excel, vba

What i want to achieve: I have an open instant of ETABS running. I want to get load cases, load combinations and storey names in listBox1, listBox2 and listBox3 respectively. when i choose any load case/ combination from list box and click button " Get reactions" in sheet1, the reactions should be displayed. currently i am not able to get the load case/comb info from etabs model to excel.

Current issue: listBox1 and ListBox2 are not able to get load cases/ load comb from open instance of ETABS

```
Public Sub ETABS_MODEL_vishwa()
       

   'create ETABS object
        Dim myHelper As cHelper
        Set myHelper = New Helper
        Set EtabsObject = myHelper.GetObject("CSI.ETABS.API.ETABSObject")

   
   'create SapModel object
       Set SapModel = EtabsObject.SapModel

    'Set present units to kNm
        ret = SapModel.SetPresentUnits(eUnits_kN_m_C)


    ' Clear existing items in ListBox1
        Sheets(1).ListBox1.Clear
    
    'Get Load cases
        ret = SapModel.LoadCases.GetNameList(NumberNames, MyName)
        
        For i = 0 To NumberNames - 1
            Sheets(1).ListBox1.AddItem MyName(i)
            Debug.Print MyName(i)
        Next i
        
    ' Clear existing items in ListBox2
        Sheets(1).ListBox2.Clear
        
    'Get Load combinations
        ret = SapModel.RespCombo.GetNameList(NumberNames, MyName)
        For i = 0 To NumberNames - 1
            Sheets(1).ListBox2.AddItem MyName(i)
        Next i
        
    Debug.Print "EtabsObject: " & TypeName(EtabsObject)
    
    Debug.Print "Number of Load Cases: " & NumberNames
        For i = 0 To NumberNames - 1
            Debug.Print "Load Case " & (i + 1) & ": " & MyName(i)
        Next i
        
    'Check if ETABS object was successfully obtained
   If EtabsObject Is Nothing Then
      MsgBox "Could not get reference to ETABS. Please make sure ETABS is open.", vbExclamation
      Exit Sub
   End If
        

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to use better names for your controls than `listBox1` through `listBox3` - why not give them meaningful names? Otherwise you code will be unmaintainable and difficult to debug.

Comment: `If EtabsObject Is Nothing Then` <-- Move this check to be immediately after the `GetObject` call, otherwise if `EtabsObject` is null then the rest of your code will fail badly before it even gets to that point (...I hope this doesn't mean you're using `On Error Resume Next`?... right? If you are, then... you've got problems)

Comment: What is `cHelper`?

Answer (score 0):

Using below code my issue was solved:

```vb
' create ETABS object
Dim myHelper As cHelper
Set myHelper = New Helper
Set EtabsObject = myHelper.GetObject("CSI.ETABS.API.ETABSObject")


' Get a reference to the active model
Set SapModel = EtabsObject.SapModel

' set as active instance
ret = EtabsObject.SetAsActiveObject
```